# SharePoint Sequential Approval Workflow is working fine in debugging stage but getting an error when deployed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, sequential-workflow

I have developed a sequential approval workflow, which is working fine while I am debugging it.

But once I deploy the workflow and start testing it again, I get inconsistent results. Some times it works fine and other times, I get the below error -

> "Error Occurred"

I am not sure as to what could be the root cause of the problem.

I have tried with testing the same scenarios (while debugging and after deployment) to eliminate any variability in testing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can find actual error by correlation if the error is giving so.

Merge-SPLogFile –Path “file path” –Correlation "Correlation"

Comment: Maybe concurrent calls on some threads... I get the same issue at times if I do some work with threads; the reason being, as far as I can tell, that debug mode is "slower" than release, breakpoints, stacks and such, so concurrent calls don't happen.

Comment: Atish, I don't have a correlation ID to use the power-shell command to find the actual error. The status of the workflow is "Error Occurred" and there is a statement in the Workflow History in Workflow Status with description "An error has occurred in WorkflowName" with Event Type as "Error" and User ID as "System Account".

Comment: Kilazur, thanks for pointing that out. Is there any solution to prevent that from occurring. If so could you please suggest the same.